# OpenCL Kernel : Parallel Summation within a __global variable

Tags: opencl

I've already learnt about the Parallel Sum Reduction technique. However, I want to know if it is possible to add up different values from different Threads to a same __global variable like this :

float a = ...; // Assign different a values for each Thread

Gvar[1] += a; // Do the sum simultaneously to the same global variable index

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For updating the same global memory location from different *work-groups* you will need to use [atomic functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomicFunctions.html).

You can do so from different *work-items* in the same group, but this is usually a bad idea. It is almost always more efficient to perform reduction in local memory within the group and only update a global memory location once in each work-group.

Note that most atomic functions are not available for floating-point data types, so you will need to either use integer types or an alternative method to solve your problem.

Comment: That's all i needed to know. Thanks